# X-Sendfile displaying 404 for handler file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, x-sendfile

I'm attempting to serve files through X-Sendfile via some creative .htaccess rewrites. Boiling it down to the bare essentials, I basically catch any incoming request and route it to a handler file, like so...

**.htaccess**:

```
# If the requested file exists...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
# Send the request to handler.php instead
RewriteRule . /handler.php [L]
```

This is the **handler.php**:

```
<?php
header( 'Content-Type: text/html' );
header( "X-My-Debug: {$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}" );
header( "X-Sendfile: {$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}" );
die();
```

Now, ideally, if I request an extant file, such as `localhost/helloworld.htm`, I should see the contents of `helloworld.htm` in the browser. Instead, I see:

**Not Found: The requested URL /handler.php was not found on this server.**

Odd, the request is routed to the handler, but that is NOT the filename being sent to X-Sendfile. Also, my custom debug header is missing from the response. So of course, the first thing I do is try the handler with...

```
<?php
header( 'Content-Type: text/html' );
header( "X-My-Debug: {$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}" );
header( "X-Sendfile: helloworld.htm" );
die();
```

If I do that, then `localhost/helloworld.html` still gives the above error... **however**, when I now access `localhost/handler.php` directly, it finally does serve me the hard-coded `helloworld.htm` content, and my debug header is now present in the response. The results are the same regardless of whether I replace the hard-coded file with a relative or absolute path.

So what am I missing here? Why is X-Sendfile giving me a 404 error on the HANDLER file when I rewrite a request, but not when I access the handler directly? And why would my custom debug header go missing?

For the record, I'm running this through MAMP 4.1.1.

Comment: Yes, the above examples are wildly unsafe. Don't do this at home. They are only meant to be streamlined examples for the sake of this specific question.

Answer (score 1):

X-Sendfile will serve a 404 NOT FOUND error page when the path is correct, but the file does not have the adequate read/write/execute permissions.  Try to chmod your file to 0644 and try again to see if it fixes the issue.